# JWT authentication not work on Iphone devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, json-server, express-jwt

i am using jwt authentication in my demo app.https://musflix.netlify.app
**my demo application github url**:https://github.com/danimadmolil/musify
i use **my forked version of json-serve-auth** https://github.com/danimadmolil/json-server-auth
i make a change to original json-serve-auth to support jwt auth throught cookies.
login function is like so:

```
(req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body as User
    const { db } = req.app

    if (db == null) {
        throw Error('You must bind the router db to the app')
    }

    const user = db.get('users').find({ email }).value() as User

    if (!user) {
        res.status(400).jsonp('Cannot find user')
        return
    }

    bcrypt
        .compare(password, user.password)
        .then((same) => {
            if (!same) throw 400

            return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
                jwt.sign(
                    { email },
                    JWT_SECRET_KEY,
                    { expiresIn: JWT_EXPIRES_IN, subject: String(user.id) },
                    (error, accessToken) => {
                        if (error) reject(error)
                        else resolve(accessToken!)
                    }
                )
            })
        })
        .then((accessToken: string) => {
            const { password: _, ...userWithoutPassword } = user
            res.cookie('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`, {
                sameSite: 'none',
                secure: true,
                httpOnly: true,
                domain: req.hostname,
                path:"/",
                expires:new Date(Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
            })
            res.status(200).jsonp({ accessToken, user: userWithoutPassword })
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            if (err === 400) res.status(400).jsonp('Incorrect password')
            else next(err)
        })
}
```

---

the code for using cookie in sever.js file in main app is like so

```
server.get("/getAllPlaylists", (req, res) => {
  let { db } = req.app;
  try {
    var { id: userId } = getUserByCookie(req);
    console.log("useriD", userId);
    if (userId) {
      return res.send(getUserPlaylists(db, userId));
    } else {
      return res.send("you are not fucking authorized");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    return res.send("error");
  }
});


function getUserByCookie(req) {
  let { db } = req.app;
  const [schema, token] = req.cookies.Authorization
    ? req.cookies.Authorization.split(" ")
    : [undefined, undefined];
  if (token && schema) {
    const { email } = jwt.verify(token, constants.JWT_SECRET_KEY);
    const user = db.get("users").find({ email }).value();
    return user;
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

there is no problem with android devices and windows systems.
the problem is when i use iphone devices (like iphone 7 or newest) when use try to login it should set a Authorization cookie to browser and then on each request (i use credential:"include" with fetch api) browser should send Authorization cookie to serve. but only on iphone devices it not sending that
i know it is a long question,i am sorry
any one can help me please?

Comment: did you found what's the problem on that and how do you solve that?

Comment: no. instead i used auth0

Comment: btw I fixed it with JWT , I will add the answer maybe somone will need it

Comment: ok, thanks. i am very interested